# Need to scroll to visible the image in table cell in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created an application to view some data using a URL. I used an `asynctask` to prevent the main thread block. But after that page is loading, I need to scroll down and up to visible my images. But It not shows every images. Here is my code.

**viewDidLoad method**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.tableView.dataSource = self;
   self.tableView.delegate = self;
   _myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                      [NSURL URLWithString:url]];

   id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                  jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
   NSArray *dataDic = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"data"];
      for (NSDictionary *dicData in dataDic) {
      Lawyer *l = [[Lawyer alloc] init];
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
          NSString *imgUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myurl%@",l.imageUrl];
          NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl]];
          UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             l.uiImage = image;
          });
        });


      [_myObject addObject:[l initFromDictionary:dicData]];

      }
}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath method**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";


   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
          UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
   Lawyer *l = [[Lawyer alloc]init];
   l = [_myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" "%@",l.firstName,l.lastName];
   cell.detailTextLabel.text = l.state;
   cell.imageView.image = l.uiImage;

   return cell;
}
```

How do I fix this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that you're using asynchronous code, and the order of lines you see in your editor is not necessarily the order in which it will execute.

Sometimes, the image on `l` gets set after `[_myObject addObject:[l init…]]` is called. Other times, it gets set before that line is called.

You are initing `l` twice, once with `[[Lawyer alloc] init]` and the second time using the `initFromDictionary:` method. Don't init it twice.

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` too, you are initing `l` twice. Don't do this.

I don't think you are clear on what pointers and instances are. Clear up your basics.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could make use of [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).  This handles all the async for you as a category on `UImageView`.  My assumption is that the problem with the images not showing is related to the `asynctask` portions of the code.  Alternatively you can peek at the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) source to see how it implements the same thing and riff on that if you prefer.